# Is it possible to create a view of a user's content and content they've flagged?

Tags: views, flags

I'm trying to build a view that displays nodes authored by a user **AND** nodes flagged by the user (but are authored by other users). All the nodes are the same content type. I can create the two views separately, but I'm wondering if there's a way to combine them into one view?